# How to make a code snippet thread safe

Tags: java, thread-safety

I have a below code. How can I make it thread safe ?

```
public interface Stub {
public void subscribe(String key);
public void unsubscribe(String key);
}

public interface Listener {
public void onEvent(String key, String event);
}
public class StubTest {

Stub stub;
ConcurrentHashMap<String,ConcurrentSkipListSet<Listener>> map = new ConcurrentHashMap<>();

public void addListener(String key, Listener listener){
    if(map.containsKey(key)){
        map.get(key).add(listener);
    }else{
        ConcurrentSkipListSet<Listener> lst = new ConcurrentSkipListSet<>();
        lst.add(listener);
        map.put(key,lst);
    }
}

public void removeListener(String key, Listener listener){
    if(map.contains(key)){
        Set<Listener> lst = map.get(key);
        lst.remove(listener);
        if(lst.size() <= 0) map.remove(key);
    }
}

public void publish(String key, String event){
    Set<Listener> lst = map.get(key);
    if(lst != null){
        lst.stream().forEach(l -> l.onEvent(key,event));
    }
}
```

}

As one can see there is lot of state maintenance in the Map however I'm open to completely rewriting the code to not maintain any state. May be using functional constructs of java 8?

Comment: You can use `computeIfAbsent` in `addListener`.

Comment: work through the public and free tutorial on concurrency: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/

Comment: Thanks @Kayaman. I'm trying to change it to `public void addListener(String key, Listener listener){`
`map.computeIfAbsent(key,k -> new ConcurrentSkipListSet<>());`
` map.computeIfPresent(key, (k,v) -> v.add(listener));`
` }`but it give me an error for lambda expression.  Error:(15, 49) java: incompatible types: bad return type in lambda expression
    boolean cannot be converted to java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentSkipListSet<Listener>